# Could there be a chronological discord in Genesis 37, 38 & 39?

Tags: genesis, contradiction

In Genesis 37 we meet Joseph when he is 17years old,then in Genesis 38 we meet Judah who marries Shua then has sons Er, Onan & Shelah,Er marries Tamar then dies & eventually Judah inpregnants Tamar, in Genesis 39 judah meets Joseph after 22 years. Could the events that in Genesis 38 have taken place within a period of 22 years?

Comment: What do you mean by a chronological discord?

Comment: Have you ever accepted (ticked) an answer to any of your questions?

Comment: collen, if you receive an answer that you think answers the question please indicate that by marking it as the answer. There is a place to mark it right under the up and down arrows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### They could have

(NOTE: Judah did not meet Joseph again until chapter 42, not chapter 39; but the 22 year time frame noted by the OP is reasonably calculated).

Not much is given in the exact chronology of events of Judah, but consider from the time of the betrayal of Joseph one (hypothetically possible) time frame that would fit:

- 1 year to meet and marry Shua's daughter (Shua was the father, not the name of the daughter, 38:12; see also 1 Chr 2:3)
- 1 year to conceive and bear Er
- 1 year to conceive and bear Onan
- 1 year to conceive and bear Shelah

Stop there a moment; we are at 4 years. We do know that Er, Onan, and Shelah do not include any twins (based on the language of v.3-5), so they came in some sequence.

Now according to Edwin M. Yamauchi,  “Cultural Aspects of Marriage in the Ancient World,” *Bibliotheca Sacra* 135 (1978): 241-242, generally for males the advisable age for marriage was between 14 to 20. So for purposes here, lets take the minimum for Er (assume he married Tamar when he was 14). That means we need to add 12 more years (since 2 of the above 4 years were after his birth).

- 12 years for Er to reach marriageable age.

We are now at 16 years total.

Let's assume 1 year passes before Er is killed by God for his wickedness (Gen 38:7), that puts Onan also at the earliest recommended marriageable age and able to perform Levirate marriage right away. But he *immediately* fails to perform his duties and is killed by God for it (Gen 38:8-10). So we added 1 more year here, and Shelah is at least 1 year out from being marriageable age.

- 1 year for marriage to Er and the very short marriage to Onan.

So Tamar is possibly twice widowed by 17 years out from the Joseph incident.

- 1 year for Shelah to come of age.
- 1 year for Judah's wife to die and Tamar to be stewing in her ire at Judah for not giving her to Shelah.
- 1 year for Tamar to meet up with Judah, conceive, and bear the twins Perez and Zerah from him.

**So a total of 20 years is possible.** One could even *reduce* that by at least 2, possible even 3 or 4 more years, if one accounted

1. that Judah may have moved quicker than the year allotted in getting married.
2. that it is only 9 months from conception to birth (so we gain a part of a year's time based off my rounding the 4 conceptions to 1 year each already, though we still need Er to reach marriageable age, which could probably only be pushed back to year 15 from Joseph's sale into slavery)
3. that Er may have married even younger than "traditionally" allotted (and Onan as well, which may be why Judah decided he would wait a bit longer for Shelah to get older)
4. that Er may have died soon after his marriage
5. that the passing of Judah's wife might have occurred during the year Shelah came of age.

### Conclusion

It is quite possible that the period of time for the events of Judah could have transpired perhaps as little as about 16 years, and fairly easily between 18 to 22 years of time. Thus fully fitting the events within the period of Joseph being sold and the brothers visiting Egypt (either the first time or the second time; the second time is the 22 year mark).

Comment: Good answer but you should probably note that there is nothing to say that Judah could not have married and had children before Joseph was sold. He was definitely older. So the chronology is not wrong but simply over overlapping. The description of marrying and having children may not be chronological narrative but back story.

Comment: @Joshua: While I agree that an overlapping chronology would solve it easily, such a chronology runs into the problem of the beginning of chapter 38 specifically stating "It came to pass **at that time** that Judah departed from his brothers" (v.1; emphasis added). The Hebrew of the first part is וַֽיְהִי֙ בָּעֵ֣ת הַהִ֔וא. So the text gives strong implication that there is a specific temporal transition from the events of selling Joseph to Judah's departure from his brothers and finding Shua's daughter. An argument of overlap would have to deal with that aspect of the text.

Comment: I admit I do not know Hebrew, so is there something special about the use of the phrase in this case? Because simply reviewing the uses for that phrase tells me it is not always a sequential signifier, but simply a "during that time, around that time" so the narrator hasn't moved on to the next generation but isn't necessarily saying "after this, then this" such as Gen 40:1. But your answer is good because it still stands up to even the harshest requirements.

Comment: In this possible timeline, how do you account for verse 12...
**Some years later** Judah’s wife died. After the time of mourning was over, Judah and his friend Hirah the Adullamite went up to Timnah to supervise the shearing of his sheep.

Comment: @MareeWorker I'm not sure what translation you are using, but that is not what the Hebrew text reads. Most translations say something like "in the process of time" or "course of time," and the Hebrew more literally reads "and [after] increasing of days" (וַיִּרְבּוּ֙ הַיָּמִ֔ים). So _years_ (שָׁנִ֖ים) are not in the statement. In my timeline, I have at least 1 year (which qualifies as an increasing of days), and could fit in another two or more and still fall within the 22 year mark, the amount plausible being dependent on how other aspects actually played out that I noted.

Comment: This doesn't take into account that as per 46:12 Perez already had two children by the time Jacob and his family moved to Egypt. Even according to your low estimate for marriage age this adds at least another decade.

Answer (score 1):

This troublesome chronology was noticed by some of the medieval commentators. Most notably, [Abraham Ibn Ezra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra) argued (in his commentary to 38:1) that at least some of the events of Judah's story must have occurred prior to the sale of Joseph, because it is not possible to fit everything into 22 years.

He points out that Judah's second son Onan had to have reached childbearing age, which he assumes must be at least 12 years old (plus at least a year and a half or so for the pregnancies of Er and Onan), then there was the unspecified time period where Tamar lived in her father's house (38:11-12), then there is the time for Tamar to become pregnant from Judah and give birth to Perez and Zerah (at least another nine months), then there is the time for Perez to reach childbearing age (at least 12 years), and father two children (at least another year and a half or so), as in 46:12 he is listed as moving to Egypt with two sons.

This calculation takes us several years past 22 years from the sale of Joseph, and that is using low estimates for every stage. Therefore the chronology of chapters 38 and 39 is not exactly in order. As to why the Bible would insert the Judah story at this point if it had actually occurred earlier, Ibn Ezra suggests that the purpose was to contrast Judah's improper sexual behavior (being seduced by Tamar) to Joseph's laudable sexual behavior (resisting the advances of his master's wife) in the next chapter.